# Управляемый код против неуправляемого при работе с X86 Intrinsics

Tags: c#, unsafe, benchmark, .net-5

Узнал, что при работе с интринсиками в `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` необязательно использовать указатели для адресации данных, а можно просто сделать каст массива данных с помощью `System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal`, и это будет работать примерно так же быстро, как через указатели в `unsafe` коде. Я удивился и протестировал производительность с помощью **Benchmark.NET**.

Написал 4 бенчмарка, скалярный для проверки результата, с использованием `System.Numerics.Vector<T>` для сверки производительности (интересно же) и собственно 2 теста на базе `Vector256<int>` с управляемым и неуправляемым кодом.

Задачу взял самую простую - сумма элементов массива из 10 миллионов элементов. У реализации есть осознаваемое мной ограничение, длина массива должна быть кратной 8 - длине вектора размерностью 256 бит (8 x 32), в противном случае результат в выводе будет непредсказуемый.

```cs
public class SumTest
{
    private static readonly int[] _numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(2, 100000000).ToArray();

    public IEnumerable<object> Params
    {
        get
        {
            yield return _numbers;
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Params))]
    public int SumScalar(int[] numbers)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            result += numbers[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Params))]
    public int SumNumerics(int[] numbers)
    {
        Vector<int> acc = Vector<int>.Zero;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i += Vector<int>.Count)
        {
            Vector<int> v = new Vector<int>(numbers, i);
            acc += v;
        }
        return Vector.Dot(acc, Vector<int>.One);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Params))]
    public int SumIntrinsics(int[] numbers)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<Vector256<int>> vectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, Vector256<int>>(numbers);
        Vector256<int> acc = Vector256<int>.Zero;
        for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
        {
            acc = Avx2.Add(acc, vectors[i]);
        }
        Vector128<int> r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(acc.GetUpper(), acc.GetLower());
        r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(r, r);
        r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(r, r);
        return r.GetElement(0);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Params))]
    public unsafe int SumIntrinsicsUnsafe(int[] numbers)
    {
        Vector256<int> acc = Vector256<int>.Zero;
        fixed (int* numPtr = numbers)
        {
            int* endPtr = numPtr + numbers.Length;
            for (int* numPos = numPtr; numPos < endPtr; numPos += 8)
            {
                Vector256<int> v = Avx.LoadVector256(numPos);
                acc = Avx2.Add(acc, v);
            }
            Vector128<int> r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(acc.GetUpper(), acc.GetLower());
            r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(r, r);
            r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(r, r);
            return r.GetElement(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Проверил вывод

```cs
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(2, 100000000).ToArray();
SumTest sum = new SumTest();
Console.WriteLine(sum.SumScalar(numbers));
Console.WriteLine(sum.SumNumerics(numbers));
Console.WriteLine(sum.SumIntrinsics(numbers));
Console.WriteLine(sum.SumIntrinsicsUnsafe(numbers));
```

```
200000000
200000000
200000000
200000000
```

То есть все ОК.

И собрал и запустил бенчмарк.

```cs
var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<SumTest>();
```

И был еще раз удивлён.

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19042
Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU 2.40GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.102
  [Host]     : .NET Core 5.0.2 (CoreCLR 5.0.220.61120, CoreFX 5.0.220.61120), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 5.0.2 (CoreCLR 5.0.220.61120, CoreFX 5.0.220.61120), X64 RyuJIT

|              Method |          numbers |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|-------------------- |----------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
|           SumScalar | Int32[100000000] | 83.69 ms | 0.466 ms | 0.436 ms |
|         SumNumerics | Int32[100000000] | 31.30 ms | 0.303 ms | 0.268 ms |
|       SumIntrinsics | Int32[100000000] | 28.98 ms | 0.282 ms | 0.236 ms |
| SumIntrinsicsUnsafe | Int32[100000000] | 28.80 ms | 0.191 ms | 0.169 ms |
```

То есть расхождение между `SumIntrinsics` и `SumIntrinsicsUnsafe` в рамках статистической погрешности (`StdDev`).

**Вопрос**: Что за зверь такой `MemoryMarshal`, и есть ли теперь смысл вообще использовать `unsafe` при работе с интринсиками, да и вообще с векторами?

*Если вопрос про то, можно ли в безопасном коде записывать результаты вычислений так же в массив - да, можно, так же каст массива и вся информация, записываемая в векторы окажется в массиве, то есть работа точно такая же как с обычным массивом структур. Другими словами преимуществ небезопасного кода с ходу не видно. Ну только если исходные данные изначально пришли в виде указателя, а не в виде управляемого массива, но и там могут быть нюансы, я не глубоко в теме.*

Кстати, приятно порадовал `Vector<T>`. Думаю, в случаях, когда код не суперчувствителен к производительности, можно использовать `Numerics` в пользу кросс-процессорности.

---

**Дополнение**

Попробовал еще переписать метод `SumNumerics` или добавил еще одну версию реализации `SumIntrinsicsHybrid`.

```cs
[Benchmark]
[ArgumentsSource(nameof(Params))]
public int SumNumerics(int[] numbers)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector<int>> vectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, Vector<int>>(numbers);
    Vector<int> acc = Vector<int>.Zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i ++)
    {
        acc += vectors[i];
    }
    return Vector.Dot(acc, Vector<int>.One);
}

[Benchmark]
[ArgumentsSource(nameof(Params))]
public unsafe int SumIntrinsicsHybrid(int[] numbers)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector256<int>> vectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, Vector256<int>>(numbers);
    Vector256<int> acc = Vector256<int>.Zero;
    fixed (Vector256<int>* numPtr = vectors)
    {
        Vector256<int>* endPtr = numPtr + vectors.Length;
        for (Vector256<int>* numPos = numPtr; numPos < endPtr; numPos++)
        {
            acc = Avx2.Add(acc, *numPos);
        }
        Vector128<int> r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(acc.GetUpper(), acc.GetLower());
        r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(r, r);
        r = Ssse3.HorizontalAdd(r, r);
        return r.GetElement(0);
    }
}
```

Бенчмарк снова показывает, что каст с помощью `MemoryMarshal` если и не бесплатен, то полностью окупается.

```
|              Method |          numbers |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|-------------------- |----------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
|           SumScalar | Int32[100000000] | 83.30 ms | 0.214 ms | 0.189 ms |
|         SumNumerics | Int32[100000000] | 28.85 ms | 0.222 ms | 0.207 ms |
|       SumIntrinsics | Int32[100000000] | 28.74 ms | 0.145 ms | 0.136 ms |
| SumIntrinsicsUnsafe | Int32[100000000] | 28.14 ms | 0.234 ms | 0.195 ms |
| SumIntrinsicsHybrid | Int32[100000000] | 28.09 ms | 0.174 ms | 0.163 ms |
```

Тест для маленького массива

```
|              Method |     numbers |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|-------------------- |------------ |----------:|---------:|---------:|
|           SumScalar | Int32[1000] | 712.65 ns | 2.889 ns | 2.702 ns |
|         SumNumerics | Int32[1000] |  81.22 ns | 0.466 ns | 0.436 ns |
|       SumIntrinsics | Int32[1000] |  82.63 ns | 0.311 ns | 0.291 ns |
| SumIntrinsicsUnsafe | Int32[1000] |  60.66 ns | 0.347 ns | 0.308 ns |
| SumIntrinsicsHybrid | Int32[1000] |  61.01 ns | 0.418 ns | 0.370 ns |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, ваш вопрос можно трансформировать в то, что такое `Span<T>`/`ReadOnlySpan<T>`. Хоть и поверхностное, но представление об этом дает обзорная статья:

- [All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/connect/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay#what-is-spant)

А если в вкратце, то интересующие вас вещи заключаются в определении типа:

```
public readonly ref struct Span<T>
{
  private readonly ref T _pointer;
  private readonly int _length;

  ...
}
```

Спан, это живущая *только* на стеке структура которая содержит в себе вот эту хитрость:

```
readonly ref T _pointer
```

Без контекста не ясно, ближе это к ссылкам или указателям в терминах C++, так что я буду использовать слово указатель. Теперь, этот новый *внутренний* тип является отслеживаемым указателем. И, в отличии от оператора `fixed` в куче теперь ничего не фиксируется, а GC сам будет менять адрес этого указателя после фазы сжатия.

Если верить документации, процедура отслеживания таких указателе дорогая с точки зрения производительности, поэтому Span был сделан [ref-структурой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#ref-struct), которая не может переехать в кучу даже в составе объекта.

> These references are called interior pointers, and tracking them is a
> relatively expensive operation for the .NET runtime’s garbage
> collector. As such, the runtime constrains these refs to only live on
> the stack, as it provides an implicit low limit on the number of
> interior pointers that might be in existence

Собственно, у спана есть продвинутые родственники `Memory<T>` и `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` которые могут обертывать не только массивы. Но статья их раскрывает слабо :-(

---

Вот ещё о чем подумалось. Если GC изменяет адрес такой ссылки динамически, после фазы сжатия. Но, как мы знаем, большие объекты попадают в [LOH](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) где уже становятся нерелоцируемыми, то если изменить ваш тест таким образом, что бы он работал с небольшими массивами но на фоне срабатывания сборщика мусора, то возможно, он покажет более-менее существенное падение производительности?

Comment: У меня в тестах нет аллкоций, массив выделяется один раз и переиспользуется для всех тестов. `[MemoryDiagnoser]` показывает прочерки на всех бенчмарках. Добавил в вопрос еще один тест для короткого массива. На нем видно небольшую просадку в управляемом коде (наверное на индексаторах) относительно указателей. Тем не менее, я пока не готов заявить, что мне теперь понятно, как оно работает. Я все еще в конфузе. У `MemoryMarshal.Cast` под капотом `Unsafe.As`, а оно уже где-то в JIT закопано.

Comment: @aepot согласен, и из `ref T _pointer` JIT тоже конструирует свой внутренний тип. Ещё одно удивительное свойство Span в том что его индексатор возвращает не копию элемента, а ссылку на него (`ref T`). А `ReadOnlySpan` возвращает константную! ссылку `ref readonly T`. Ждем семантику переноса в .net :-)